# non matching parameters Mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the error that

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   C:\wamp64\www\testing\view.php on line 17

Can Anyone see what I'm doing wrong because i can see it matching

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();

}

$query = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);

if($stmt){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iss",$id, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$id, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);   
    echo "ID: ".$id. "Username: ".$username."Password: ".$password;


    }
?>
```

Comment: You don't have any placeholders in a query. Are you sure that you understand how prepared statements work?

Comment: From where did you get value in these variables `$id, $username, $password`?

Comment: Yes. You haven't understand at all how prepared statements work. http://bobby-tables.com - Have a look here. 
You're actually trying to bind variables to a query without any reason, since you have no placeholders in it. 
Also you try to bind the result before you even execute the query. You should go a step back and read some tutorials on how `mysqli_*` works and try to understand it. Actually, you haven't understand it at all (thats not a problem, you'll get fast into it), but right now I really recommend you to learn it. It won't help you if I rewrite your code.

Comment: Someone needs to go back to the official manuals and stick to the syntax.

Comment: WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED/PREPARED BEFORE CODING?

Answer (score 0):

I looked up and read up on Prepared statements further and started from scratch but with a registration form appose to login form. Kindly advise if this is the correct way of posting securely this information as it seems the be working. In addition is there a way to check before posting that the email is not a duplicate? As i tried to do this and getting commands out of sync error. I could not work out how to get round this. If anyone could point me int the right direction that would be much appreciated.

```html
<?php
require ("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['reg'])) {
 
   
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $about = $_POST['about'];
    $type = $_POST['type']; 
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
  

 if (empty($username)) {
  $msg = "Please create your username";
 } elseif (empty($password)) {
  $msg = "Please create your password";
 } elseif (empty($email)) {
  $msg = "Please enter your email"; 
 } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $msg = "Invalid email format";  

 } else {
 
    if(!($stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, about, type) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"))){
        echo "Failed: (" . $connect->errno . ")" . $connect->error;
    }

    if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $password_hash, $email, $about, $type)){
     echo "Failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
    }

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
     echo "Failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
    }

    if($stmt) {
  echo "Registration Success!!";

    }
    else{
        echo "Registration failed";
    }
 }

 }
$connect->close();
?>
```

Comment: This should be posted as a question, not as an answer.